# xcode ios 7 and ios 8 screen bounds bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation

Hello everyone i am using latest xcode and 2 devices(identical). One with iOS 7 and the other one with iOS 8

In portrait mode on iOS 7 i get the resolution 1024x768 (which is landscape)
In portrait mode on iOS 8 i get the resolution 768x1024 ( actual portrait )

The problem is that i use the same methods any one could help me building a function and accessing it much easier ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

this is my code

```
CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:screenWidth forKey:@"scwidth"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:screenHeight forKey:@"scheight"];
```

Comment: Is your app locked to portrait (so the width is always < the height)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i made a method for you , you can execute it at first run , it will save the screenResolutions in NSUserDefaults

It will work only with iOS6++

```
-(void)loadResolution{
    NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    int ver_int = [ver intValue];
    if(ver_int > 6)
    {
        CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:screenWidth forKey:@"scwidth"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:screenHeight forKey:@"scheight"];

    }

    if(ver_int > 7.9)
    {

        CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:screenWidth forKey:@"scwidth"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:screenHeight forKey:@"scheight"];

    }
    NSLog(@"Loading Resolution...OK");

}
```

Retrieve the screen bounds with this

```
NSInteger screenWidth = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scwidth"];
NSInteger screenHeight = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scheight"];
```

Comment: why on earth would you save this to NSUserDefaults (or anywhere) when you can fetch it anytime??  what if the device is updated from iOs6 to 7 subsequently to your saving a value ??

In my opinion this is a flawed answer, weak design built on assumption.  Apple has changed the way they do this, how do you know they will not do so again?  Use fMinf() / fMaxf() or similar functions to fetch the greater and lesser dimensions rather than assume behavious and checking version numbers.  Sorry, but its lazy.

Comment: @Jef If he calls the method at viewdidLoad and rewrites the NSUserDefaults every time it's ok ,

Comment: Yes. but if you call it at every load then why not just call it every time you need it? that is to say why save it anywhere at all? Is the device likely to be plugged into a different sized screen on next (or this) launch?  If this does happen do we want the old screen size or the current one?  Its an abuse / misuse of NSUserDefaults, and for no apparent reason/gain, NSUserDefaults is for persisting data that might actually differ from time to time or from install to install.

This is not personal, and i make no down vote, just constructive criticism, an opportunity for you to polish your code